# Highcharts: Tooltip on a single series only

Tags: highcharts

I have 3 datasets within my series (low, normal, high) displaying on a scatter plot. 
How can I force the tooltip and markers to be enabled only for the normal data set?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**formatter**: Function
Callback function to format the text of the tooltip. **Return false to disable tooltip for a specific point on series**.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter

Answer (score 0):

See shared tooltip formatter. It gives you better control over the tooltip.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip

EDIT: I have added some code. See the custom tooltip formatter;

```
tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                if (this.series.name == "Male") {
                    return "<b>" + this.series.name + "</b><br>" + this.x + " cm, " + this.y + " kg";
                } else return " ";

            }
        }
```

See the fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/androdify/cweC6/

Comment: Many thanks but this is not quite what I am looking for. Shared tooltips enables the tooltip across several series. I want the tooltip to work on one series only and not to work at all on the others (ie no stickyness, tooltip, selection etc).

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for keeping tooltips on all series, but only display one tooltip at a time corresponding to the point actually hovered over.

Look through the code for where it is specifying a variable by the name of hoverPoints and change it to this:

```
{hoverPoint:l,hoverSeries:b,hoverPoints:l?[l]:[]}
```

This is the code for Highstock, so if you are using vanilla Highcharts you may need to change variable names around a bit. To explain how this works, the default value for hoverpoints is an array of all points on that spot on the x axis. Changing it to an array containing the single point that you actually hovered over, the value of hoverPoint, causes highcharts to ignore the other hit points.