# How do I catch a click event on a polygon in HighCharts without having the tooltip popping up

Tags: events, highcharts, polygon

I have a chart

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        series: [{
            type: 'polygon',
            data: [[153, 42], [149, 46], [166, 45]],
            color: '#ff0000',
            enableMouseTracking: true,
            events: {
                click: function(event) {
                    alert("I am clicked");
                }            
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

In the chart I have a polygon. I need to catch the client event that tells me the polygon I have clicked. I have several problems here.

1) I cannot get it to fire the event without enableMouseTracking being true, which gives me the tooltips
2) Event if I accept the tooltips, then I dont seem have access to information on the polygon I am clicking from the event.

I hope someone has an answer

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polygon series can be accessed via event.currentTarget.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ow72qjaw/

Tooltip can be disabled by setting:

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: false
}
```

Hover effects can be disabled for series by using proper settings:

```
states: {
    hover: {
        enabled: false
    }
}
```

If you want to disable tooltip for selected series only you can see similar topics:

[Disable tooltip on certain points in Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785886/disable-tooltip-on-certain-points-in-highcharts)

[Highcharts: Tooltip on a single series only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346384/highcharts-tooltip-on-a-single-series-only)